# WordPress: How can change customise user emails message

Tags: wordpress, email

I need to change all of message of :-

New user active.
New User Welcome Email.
Password Reminder Email.

So I need to change all `Customise User Emails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email functions in Wordpress are pluggable, which means you can overwrite them with your own.

If you are a beginner and want to solve this fast, I believe a plugin is the way to go, I found this one that seems fine - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails/

**EDIT -** The plugin above doesn't seem to solve the problem, in fact, there seems to be no plugin to edit all the system generated plugins at once.

This tutorial seems the way to go - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/25/create-perfect-emails-wordpress-website/

Basically what we need to do is to redefine the functions, as stated:

> The function in question is called wp_new_user_notification(). To
>   modify it, all we need to do is create a function with the same name.
>   Due to the method by which WordPress calls pluggable functions, there
>   will not be any conflict, even though you are creating a function with
>   the same name. Below is the function that I wrote. See the explanation
>   and preview of it further below.

So for example, to edit the User registration Email, you ned to edit the function wp_new_user_notification(). To do that, just add the code below to your functions.php:

```
function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass) {
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);

    $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
    $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

    $email_subject = "Welcome to MyAwesomeSite ".$user_login."!";

    ob_start();

    include("email_header.php");

    ?>

    <p>A very special welcome to you, <?php echo $user_login ?>. Thank you for joining MyAwesomeSite.com!</p>

    <p>
        Your password is <strong style="color:orange"><?php echo $plaintext_pass ?></strong> <br>
        Please keep it secret and keep it safe!
    </p>

    <p>
        We hope you enjoy your stay at MyAwesomeSite.com. If you have any problems, questions, opinions, praise, 
        comments, suggestions, please feel free to contact us at any time
    </p>


    <?php
    include("email_footer.php");

    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    wp_mail($user_email, $email_subject, $message);
```

Comment: I try using this plugin - `https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails/` but i don't understand it is not for my need, and the second link iam new in WordPress and i need plugin its good

Comment: @KotshMan I've edited the original answer, it now contains code to help you sorting out the solution.